# Mounting a docker external volume directory as a host (lvm) partition, will this work?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, docker

I have a lot of containers that grow uncomfortably quickly; for instance, databases.
When you create an external docker volume (`docker volume create {volume_name}`), I see it listed in the docker volumes directory under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/{volume_name}`.

Is it okay to mount `volume_name` directory on a, say, LVM partition so I can use the host OS to extend the partition easily?
I've actually tried this for a mysql container, but when I did, I don't see any files inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes/{volume_name}/`.

Is this a valid thing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do that, your best bet would be do create an LV that mounts at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volname>` before creating the volume in Docker. I also just tried on my laptop. I created the LV mounted at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/demo`, mounted it, then created the volume `demo` in Docker and everything seemed happy.

*Alternatively, Docker's [direct-lvm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) mode might also address this.*

Quoting: "The devicemapper driver uses block devices dedicated to Docker and operates at the block level, rather than the file level. These devices can be extended by adding physical storage to your Docker host, and they perform better than using a filesystem at the level of the operating system."

Comment: I’m trying to have each individual volume occupy its own space without them all fighting for storage on a single device.

Comment: I'm actually editing my answer as I thought about it a little bit more.

Comment: Yes, you’ve described exactly what I did. And everything seems happy, but I can’t tell if files are written in the LVs. I’m just hoping this doesn’t blow up in my face.

Comment: Just track the directory size of your mounted LV and then you'll know. :)

Comment: Amen. And if they don’t grow?

Comment: Try the direct-lvm mode I mentioned above but I would see no reason why having the direct LV will fail in any way.